# Why is this neo4j-ogm code producing 'invalid syntax'?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have some spring-data-neo4j / ogm code that is unexpectedly failing.

```
public Member loadMemberBySocialMediaAccount(String connectionKey) {
        String[] connectionKeyParts = connectionKey.split(":");
        Filters filters = new Filters()
                .add(new Filter("providerId", connectionKeyParts[0]))
                .add(new Filter("providerUserId", connectionKeyParts[1]));
        Iterator<SocialMediaAccount> socialMediaAccounts = session.loadAll(SocialMediaAccount.class, filters, 2).iterator();
        return socialMediaAccounts.hasNext() ? socialMediaAccounts.next().getMember() : null;
}
```

When I dig into the ogm code I can see the following exception is thrown. Is this expected?

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: "errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax","message":"Invalid input 'n': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', \"=~\", IN, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', \"<=\", \">=\", '=', \"<>\", \"!=\", AND, XOR, OR, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 72 (offset: 71))\n\"MATCH (n:`SocialMediaAccount`) WHERE n.`providerId` = { `providerId` } n.`providerUserId` = { `providerUserId` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..2]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n)\"\n                                                                        ^"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the tests, and what is expected is that all filters except the first must have a BooleanOperator defined (AND or OR).

So in your case:

```
Filters filters = new Filters()
                .add(new Filter("providerId", connectionKeyParts[0]));
Filter providerUserIdFilter = new Filter("providerUserId", connectionKeyParts[1]);
providerUserIdFilter.setBooleanOperator(BooleanOperator.AND);
filters.add(providerUserIdFilter);
```

I've opened https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/73 to for us to figure out whether it is feasible to default the BooleanOperator for subsequent filters to AND.